# Synchronous mode in XMLHTTPRequest in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

As per the link below, synchronous mode for XHR is being deprecated in Firefox. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Here is what document says:

> Starting with Gecko 30.0 (Firefox 30.0 / Thunderbird 30.0 / SeaMonkey 2.27), synchronous requests on the main thread have been deprecated due to the negative effects to the user experience.

I wanted to know if Chrome is going to follow this? Would it be safe to use synchronous XMLHTTPReuquest in Chrome extension? (For business reason, it needs to synchronous in my case)

Comment: It is already deprecated for Chrome Apps. I guess they only keep them for extensions for legacy reasons.

Comment: Also, you do understand it's a question only (possibly) Chrome devs can answer?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=165298

Comment: Xan,  It is currently working in the extension and chrome documentation does not mention anything about deprecation of this capability. Yes, I am looking forward for definitive answer from someone close to Chrome project. thanks for comment.

Comment: You're asking us to predict the future here. It would be more appropriate ask the Chrome team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a Chrome developer and it will be deprecated eventually but not in a backwards incompatible way.